# Summing observations vertically in SAS by multiple variables

Tags: sql, sum, sas

I am currently dealing with a data set that includes sales for multiple store locations over the course of 300 weeks. Each week and store combination contains multiple items that need to be summed together. Somehow I need to find the sum of sales for all the items for each week for each store and output that to a data set. I have tried using proc sql, but am unable to sort it by week and store. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SAS is the 'database', given the question, tags, and title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

Assumptions:

1. Your database is SQL Server (you didn't specify your database in the question)
2. Your location field is called location_id.
3. Your date field is called datefield and it is a date data type.
4. Your amount field is called sales.
5. Your table is called tbl.

(replace as needed)

```
select location_id,
       concat(datepart(yyyy, datefield), '-', datepart(wk, datefield)) as weekofyr,
       sum(sales) as sum_sales
  from tbl
 group by location_id,
          concat(datepart(yyyy, datefield), '-', datepart(wk, datefield))
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful, it runs perfectly now!

Answer (score 3):

The SAS-sy solution to this is `PROC MEANS`.

```
proc means data=have;
class location week;
var sales;
output out=want sum(sales)=;
run;
```